# java generics - how to implement a class that takes a HashSet<T>?

Tags: java, generics

Normally when you implement a generic, you have some type `T` that you want to generalize. I want to write a class that generalizes a `HashSet<T>`.

I'm trying to write this the following way, but it's not the correct syntax or maybe it's not supported:

```
public class PermutationHelper<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private HashSet<T> m_set;
    private long numberOfPermutations;
    private boolean includeEmptyPermutationAsOutput = false;

    public PermutationHelper(HashSet<T> set) {
        m_set = set;
        numberOfPermutations = 2 ^ set.size();
    }

    public void setIncludeEmptyPermutationAsOutput(boolean value) {
        includeEmptyPermutationAsOutput = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        Iterator<T> it = new Iterator<T>() {

            long currentIndex = (includeEmptyPermutationAsOutput ? 0 : 1);

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return currentIndex < numberOfPermutations;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                HashSet<T> result = new HashSet<T>();
                return result;  // expects T, but is a HashSet<T>..
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
        return it;
    }
}
```

I want the Iterator to give me all subsets of the passed-in `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: Just use `T` as a parameter and refer to `HashSet<T>` when appropriate? i.e. is there some reason `Helper<T>` doesn’t work for you?

Comment: Also I hope you're not going to name your class `Helper`.

Comment: it is possible but depends what you want to implement, there are other options too

Comment: I edited the question.  I guess I over-simplified trying to keep things simple.  Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easly do

`public class PermutationHelper<T extends HashSet<T>> implements Iterable<T>`

in order to 'force' the generic type to be an HashSet or a subtype of a HashSet

Answer (score 1):

What you want is simply

```
public class PermutationHelper<T> implements Iterable<HashSet<T>>
```

Your class is generic. You choose to name its generic type T. And it implements `Iterable<HashSet<T>>`, which means it must have a method

```
public Iterator<HashSet<T>> iterator()
```